# Interpretation of fitted model with 'auto.arima'

Tags: regression, time-series

I'm a little bit confused about the fitted results given by `auto.arima` when I was trying to fit a regression model with ARIMA error.
The example is

```
> fit<-auto.arima(M1Germany[,1],xreg=M1Germany[,2])
> summary(fit)
Series: M1Germany[, 1] 
Regression with ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,1,2)[4] errors 

Coefficients:
         ar1     sma1     sma2   drift     xreg
      0.9088  -0.6371  -0.2135  0.0134  -0.6540
s.e.  0.0399   0.0983   0.0958  0.0017   0.1644

sigma^2 estimated as 0.0003438:  log likelihood=360.37
AIC=-708.75   AICc=-708.11   BIC=-691.1

Training set error measures:
                       ME       RMSE        MAE        MPE      MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.0004924726 0.01795294 0.01415854 0.00625389 0.1662376 0.3572648 0.03499876
}
```

I'm wondering where the drift should be. My guess is 
$$Y_t=-0.6540X_t+W_t$$,where the $W_t$ satisfies $$(1-.9088B)(1-B^4)(W_t-0.0134t)=(1-0.6371B^4-0.2135B^8)Z_t.$$
Am I right? And what if we get an intercept rather than a drift, where should the intercept be? Like this one? 
$$(1-.9088B)(1-B^4)(W_t-intercept)=(1-0.6371B^4-0.2135B^8)Z_t.$$